# Upgrade Spring Webflow from 1.0.6 to 2.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

we've got a large web-app based on Spring 2.5.6 and Webflow 2.3. Now we want to upgrade Spring to 3 and Webflow to 2.3. Upgrading Spring was quite painless, but we have some problems with the other lib. After changing version, we can't even build our app with maven. There are large differences e.g.: packages names, methods visibility modifiers and even deleted methods, which we are using in 1.0.6.
Do you now some guides, how should we replace changed methods? I found something like that on Spring site, but it is not quite usefull for me.
Maybe someone does that and can give us some tips?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Have you tried asking on the Spring forum for webflow?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. Carefully read through the Spring Documentation for the release. You will need to use the reference documentation for 1.0.X & 2.3.X as this will be helpful. Pay particular attention to the following changes as recommended by the upgrade guide.

Step 1. I wrote a small tool that extends the upgrader below to recursively find all our web flows and to transform the tags to be 2.3.X compliant:

```
java org.springframework.webflow.upgrade.WebFlowUpgrader flow-to-upgrade.xml
```

This class is found in the WebFlow jars source.

Step 2. I updated the schema:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd">
```

Step 3. Confirm the flowExecutor tag is updated to 2.3 compliance:

```
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" />
```

Step 4. Update the flowRegistry for static path based declaration and ensure tag compliance:

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry">
    <webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/hotels/booking/booking.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

Step 5. Change the FlowController class to match the new Web Flow jar:
Changed from `org.springframework.webflow.executor.mvc.FlowController` and is now `org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController`

Step 6. Update the the FlowController bean class reference. Adding the WebFlow1FlowUrlHandler ensure Web Flow 1.0.x flows will run an be backwards compatible with the new Web Flow 2 jars.

```
<bean name="/pos.htm" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    <property name="flowUrlHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.context.servlet.WebFlow1FlowUrlHandler" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/#upgrade-guide

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.1/reference/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give here concrete advices. Upgrading is always a hard stuff. First of all I encourage you to read a section about upgrading in the webflow documentation for example from here http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/pdf/spring-webflow-reference.pdf (Chapter 16 - Upgrading from 1.0) doing this you can see what has changed since version 1.0. Then you can decide if upgrade is reasonable. Good luck ! :)